# Is there any reason not to force sys.path when running with mod_wsgi on apache?

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

So, after getting frustrated one time too many with the path situation under mod_wsgi and apache I took the brute force hammer to it.

Now I'm wondering if there are any possible other pitfalls.

I activated my virtualenv then ran

```
(virtualenv)$python
>>> import sys
>>> for i in sys.path:
>>>   print "'{}',".format(i)
>>> quit()
```

then I pasted that into my wsgi file like so:

```
import sys
sys.path = [

    Block of stuff printed out

]
```

This way sys.path is the same for apache as it is when I'm running the debug server.

Everything else has always talked about inserting things into the path, Is there some reason this won't just work?

Not that is should matter, but its a django project.

Comment: Wholesale replacing of sys.path is very bad practice. So long as you setup mod_wsgi and do things in your script correctly things should be fine. Explain properly in your question why you had to do this so we can fix the original problem rather than fixing your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention to use virtualenv, did you make sure that apache/mod_wsgi uses the virtualenv path, i.e. activate this is used? Try to add it like that to your wsgi file:

```
activate_this = join(VIRTUALENV_DIR,'bin/activate_this.py')
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of that actually.  I'm running a fairly large pinax app with several other apps loaded via `pip install -e`.  That might have been a good idea.